# ERROR: Define not done before fetch or execute and fetch

Tags: c, database, oracle, oracle-call-interface

My application receive query from external source (config file), so that it have to obtain columns from query result. I have some piece of code:

```
typedef union _DbField {
    text text[512];
    sword integer;
    double precise;
} DbField;

typedef struct _Arg {
    size_t argSize;
    DbField field;
} Arg;
OCIEnv *envhp;
OCISession *authp = (OCISession *) 0;
OCIError *errhp;
OCISvcCtx *svchp;
OCIServer *srvhp;
OCIStmt *statementHandler;
OCIDefine *defnp = (OCIDefine *) 0;
sword status;

...

//int main()

    status = OCIEnvCreate((OCIEnv **) &envhp, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT, (dvoid *) 0,
            (dvoid * (*)(dvoid *, size_t)) 0, (dvoid * (*)(dvoid *, dvoid *, size_t)) 0,
            (void (*)(dvoid *, dvoid *)) 0, (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);

    checkError(0, __LINE__);

    status = OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *) envhp, (dvoid **) &errhp, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR, (size_t) 0,
            (dvoid **) 0);
    checkError(0, __LINE__);

    status = OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *) envhp, (dvoid **) &srvhp, OCI_HTYPE_SERVER, (size_t) 0,
            (dvoid **) 0);
    checkError(0, __LINE__);

    status = OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *) envhp, (dvoid **) &svchp, OCI_HTYPE_SVCCTX, (size_t) 0,
            (dvoid **) 0);
    checkError(0, __LINE__);

    status = OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *) envhp, (dvoid **) &statementHandler, OCI_HTYPE_STMT,
            (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);
    checkError(0, __LINE__);

    status = OCIServerAttach(srvhp, errhp, (text *) connection->dbName, (sb4) strlen((char *) connection->dbName), 0);
    status = OCIServerAttach(srvhp, errhp, (text *) "", (sb4) strlen((char *) ""), 0);
    checkError(0, __LINE__);

    status = OCIAttrSet((dvoid *) svchp, OCI_HTYPE_SVCCTX, (dvoid *) srvhp, (ub4) 0,
    OCI_ATTR_SERVER, (OCIError *) errhp);
    if (status != 0) {
        printf("HANDLER ERROR %d !!!\n\n", status);
        exit(2);
    }

    (void) OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *) envhp, (dvoid **) &authp, (ub4) OCI_HTYPE_SESSION,
            (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);

    (void) OCIAttrSet((dvoid *) authp, (ub4) OCI_HTYPE_SESSION, (dvoid *) connection->userName,
            (ub4) strlen((char *) connection->userName), (ub4) OCI_ATTR_USERNAME, errhp);

    (void) OCIAttrSet((dvoid *) authp, (ub4) OCI_HTYPE_SESSION,
            (dvoid *) connection->userPassword,
            (ub4) strlen((char *) connection->userPassword), (ub4) OCI_ATTR_PASSWORD, errhp);

    status = OCISessionBegin(svchp, errhp, authp, OCI_CRED_RDBMS, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT);

    (void) OCIAttrSet((dvoid *) svchp, (ub4) OCI_HTYPE_SVCCTX, (dvoid *) authp, (ub4) 0,
            (ub4) OCI_ATTR_SESSION, errhp);
    errhp, OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *) envhp, (dvoid **) &statementHandler, OCI_HTYPE_STMT,
            (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);

    executeStatement("SELECT * FROM logs order by log_id");


//end of int main()

static inline sword executeStatement(char *statement) {
    int rowsFetched = 0;
    int forSecond = 0;
    ub4 numcols = 0;
    ub2 dtype = 0;
    OCIStmt *structureHandler;
    OCIParam *colhd = (OCIParam *) 0;
    char *statementCopy = malloc(strlen(statement));
    memcpy(statementCopy, statement, strlen(statement));

    status = OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *) envhp, (dvoid **) &structureHandler, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, (size_t) 0, (dvoid **) 0);
    checkError(1, __LINE__);

    status = OCIStmtPrepare(structureHandler, errhp, statementCopy, (ub4) strlen((char *) statement), (ub4)OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, (ub4) OCI_NO_SHARING);
    checkError(1, __LINE__);
    status = OCIStmtExecute(svchp, structureHandler, errhp, (ub4) 1, (ub4) 0,(const OCISnapshot *) NULL, (OCISnapshot *) NULL, (ub4) OCI_DESCRIBE_ONLY);
    checkError(1, __LINE__);
    OCIAttrGet((dvoid *)structureHandler, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, (dvoid *)&numcols, (ub4 *)0, OCI_ATTR_PARAM_COUNT, errhp);
    ub2 colTypes[numcols];
    Arg columns[numcols];
    for (int a = 0; a < numcols; ++a) {
        OCIParamGet((dvoid *)structureHandler, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, errhp, (dvoid **)&colhd, a+1);
        OCIAttrGet((dvoid *)colhd, OCI_DTYPE_PARAM,(dvoid *)&dtype, (ub4 *)0, OCI_ATTR_DATA_TYPE, errhp);
        colTypes[a] = dtype;
        printf("Coltype %d\t\t", colTypes[a]);
        if (colTypes[a] == SQLT_INT || colTypes[a] == SQLT_NUM) {
            columns[a].argSize = sizeof(int);
            printf("Param is %d INT, size %d ", a, columns[a].argSize);
            status = OCIDefineByPos(statementHandler, &defnp, errhp, a+1, (dvoid *)&(columns[a].field.integer), (sword) columns[a].argSize, colTypes[a], (dvoid *) 0, (ub2 *) 0, (ub2 *) 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
            if (status == 0) {
                printf("Param %d bind OK\n", a+1);
            } else {
                printf("Binding %d param caused error!!!\n", a+1);
            }
            fflush(stdout);
        } else if (colTypes[a] == SQLT_STR || colTypes[a] == SQLT_CLOB) {
            columns[a].argSize = sizeof(char)*1024;
            status = OCIDefineByPos(statementHandler, &defnp, errhp, a+1, (dvoid *)&(columns[a].field.text), (sword) columns[a].argSize, colTypes[a], (dvoid *) 0, (ub2 *) 0, (ub2 *) 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
            printf("Param is %d STR, size %d ", a, columns[a].argSize);
            if (status == 0) {
                printf("Param %d bind OK\n", a+1);
            } else {
                printf("Binding %d param caused error!!!\n", a+1);
            }
            fflush(stdout);
        } else if (colTypes[a] == SQLT_TIMESTAMP) {
            columns[a].argSize = sizeof(char)*768;
            status = OCIDefineByPos(statementHandler, &defnp, errhp, a+1, (dvoid *)&(columns[a].field.text), (sword) columns[a].argSize, colTypes[a], (dvoid *) 0, (ub2 *) 0, (ub2 *) 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
            printf("Param is %d TIMESTAMP, size %d ", a, columns[a].argSize);
            if (status == 0) {
                printf("Param %d bind OK\n", a+1);
            } else {
                printf("Binding %d param caused error!!!\n", a+1);
            }
            fflush(stdout);
        } else {
            //Other types are not needed for me right now
            perror("Invalid column type\n\n");
            printf("Other type for [%d]: %d\n", a, colTypes[a]);
            fflush(stdout);
            exit(3);
        }

    }

    status = OCIStmtPrepare(statementHandler, errhp, statement, (ub4) strlen((char *) statement), (ub4)OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT);
    checkError(0, __LINE__);
    //ERROR IN LINE ABOVE
    status = OCIStmtExecute(svchp, statementHandler, errhp, (ub4) 1, (ub4) 0,(const OCISnapshot *) NULL, (OCISnapshot *) NULL, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT);
    checkError(0, __LINE__);

    status = OCIAttrGet(statementHandler, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, (void*)&rowsFetched, NULL, OCI_ATTR_ROWS_FETCHED, errhp);
    printf("Total rows: %d, status %d.\n", rowsFetched, status);

    if (rowsFetched == 0) {
        printf("No data!\n");
        return OCI_NO_DATA;
    }

    do {
        printf("ROW ");
        for (int a = 0; a < numcols; ++a) {
            if (colTypes[a] == SQLT_INT || colTypes[a] == SQLT_NUM) {
                printf(" INT %d", columns[a].field.integer);
            } else if (colTypes[a] == SQLT_STR || colTypes[a] == SQLT_CLOB) {
                printf(" TXT %s", columns[a].field.text);
            } else if (colTypes[a] == SQLT_TIMESTAMP) {
                printf(" TIMESTAMP %s", columns[a].field.text);
            } else {
                perror("Invalid column type\n\n");
                printf("Other type for [%d]: %d\n", a, colTypes[a]);
                fflush(stdout);
                exit(3);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        status = OCIStmtFetch2(statementHandler, errhp, 1, OCI_DEFAULT, (sb4) 1, OCI_DEFAULT);
    } while (status != OCI_NO_DATA && status != OCI_ERROR);

    return OCI_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code in marked line causes error ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or executeand fetch. My application says that columns count is matching to query and binding is OK. I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move this line:

```
status = OCIStmtPrepare(statementHandler, errhp, statement, (ub4) strlen((char *) statement), (ub4)OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT);
```

... to before you start calling `OCIDefineByPos(statementHandler, ...)`.

It could be the first OCI call in `executeStatement` really, before you do anything with `structureHandler`. But it needs to be before the `for (int a = 0; a < numcols; ++a)` loop, anyway.

I believe the order wasn't enforced as strongly in earlier releases (9i and before?), but now you have to prepare before you can define the bind variables.

Comment: Now I have segmentation fault.

Comment: @PingwinTux - I don't get a fault; I had to make some of the code up and it only seems to recognise numeric columns and gets the number wrong (`select 10 from dual` shows `ROW  INT 3009` for example), so I'm doing something different anyway... Is if faulting in the code you posted or somewhere else though?

Comment: Indeed, segmentation fault was related with pointer to char[]. Integers don't crash but values still are wrong. It seems like pointers given to OCIDefineByPos are invalid.

Comment: @PingwinTux - you seem to be conflating types; SQLT_INT and SQLT_NUM aren't interchangeable. If you force the bind to use SQLT_INT (since you're binding to an int in the structure) it gets the right value. But you might not only be dealing with integers, of course. For your sigsegv, the bind for the .text field doesn't need the `&`?

Comment: Now I have correct numbers.So, should I have  
status = OCIDefineByPos(statementHandler, &defnp, errhp, a+1, (dvoid *)(columns[a].text), (sword) columns[a].argSize, colTypes[a], (dvoid *) 0, (ub2 *) 0, (ub2 *) 0, OCI_DEFAULT);  

for type char[512]?

Comment: OK, now everything works fine. Thank you for patience and help.